# Lazy query.list() in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 3.3.2 GA + Annotations. Is there a way get a lazy list back when calling list() on a query? The documentation (19.1.3) remarks:

> list() does not usually return proxies.

The question is: how **do** I make it return proxies (or more perhaps more precisely one proxy which returns entity instances during the actual iteration)? Is that possible at all? How would I tune the batch size?

Comment: Is it the answer you need?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287702/how-can-we-reduce-the-unnecessary-loading-of-objects/1288238#1288238

Comment: I wrote my own implementation using result iterators (which could easily be optimized using scroll() and reasonable page sizes). Still I wonder how this problem should be solved using Hibernate alone.

Comment: @Vanger: nope - I know how to lazily fetch assocations. I need lazy (first level) entity fetching ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Query.iterate](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#iterate()) is what you want?

Comment: I wanted the convenience of having a collection class of (potentially) unlimited size without having to iterate explicitly. I ended up writing a lazy list which uses scrollable results internally.